# What is the ms-vscode.cpptools extension?

Tags: c++

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code (it is basically a glorified command prompt), it keeps recommending that I download the ms-vscode.cpptools extension. Has anyone download it already and know what it is?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools

Answer (score 0):

It is an extension for C/C++ in Visual Studio Code.

> This preview release of the extension adds language support for C/C++ to Visual Studio Code

You can find it and its Details easily in Markt.

I guess it keeps recommending you to download it because you are editing c/c++ files.